# Grails 3.x- GORM - inList fails on members start with underscore (_)

Tags: constraints, grails-orm, grails3, grails-3.1

I have this class

```
class ScanRequest4Command implements Validateable {

    String _ScanType

    static constraints = {
        pScanType inList:["a", "b"]
    }
}
```

this code worked fine in grails 2.4.4
lately, we started upgrading to grails 3.1.16

now when I try to run the code if fails and throw the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: object is not an instance of declaring class
    at com.evercompliant.commands.v4.ScanRequest4Command$__clinit__closure9.doCall(ScanRequest4Command.groovy:151)
    at com.evercompliant.commands.v4.ScanRequest4Command$__clinit__closure9.doCall(ScanRequest4Command.groovy)
    at com.evercompliant.commands.v4.ScanRequest4Command$__clinit__closure9.call(ScanRequest4Command.groovy)
    at com.evercompliant.commands.v4.ScanRequest4Command$__clinit__closure9.call(ScanRequest4Command.groovy)
    at com.evercompliant.commands.v4.ScanRequest4Command.validate(ScanRequest4Command.groovy)
    at com.evercompliant.commands.v4.ScanRequest4Command.validate(ScanRequest4Command.groovy)
    at com.evercompliant.commands.v4.Base4Command.validateWithErrors(Base4Command.groovy:98)
    at com.evercompliant.commands.v4.PortfolioManagementBase4Command.validateWithErrors(PortfolioManagementBase4Command.groovy)
    at com.evercompliant.commands.v4.ScanRequest4Command.super$2$validateWithErrors(ScanRequest4Command.groovy)
    at com.evercompliant.commands.v4.ScanRequest4Command.validateWithErrors(ScanRequest4Command.groovy:164)
    at com.evercompliant.commands.v4.ScanRequest4Command$validateWithErrors.call(Unknown Source)
    at com.evercompliant.data.Merchant.withTransaction(Merchant.groovy)
    at com.evercompliant.data.Merchant$withTransaction.call(Unknown Source)
    at com.evercompliant.utils.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:35)
```

which did not help much.
if I remove the `inList` constraint the code passes, meaning the problem is in the `inList` constraint.

so after test-and-failed, I found out the if I change the member's name to `pScanType` the code passes.

so my question is this:

> is the underscore not allowed in member name prefix? if so is it
>   documented anywhere? if not then what is the problem with the code?

Comment: you have different names for your field and constraint: `_ScanType` and `pScanType`

Comment: @injecteer yes, that's what I meant. if I change the name of the field, the code works

Comment: Maybe try with anohter grails version (https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/10428)

Comment: @Kloker did reproduce in 3.3, decided later that we want grails 3.1 for now since we don't want to upgrade hibernate

Comment: @NoIdeaForName - I imagine this was all sorted ages ago, but why not just use the same name in both the filed declaration and the constraint block? Using two different names is confusing, and if it did work in the past, it probably shouldn't have.